# Diferença entre ADO.NET e Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, dapper

Qual a diferenças entre os ORM's? Quando usar um e quando usar o outro? Quais as vantagens de desvantagens de cada um?

Comment: Dapper funciona em cima do ADO.NET... ele implementa métodos de extensão para a interface IDbConnection... e mapeia os dados com os objetos: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: Só pra ver se compreendi, o Dapper ele busca os dados e já mapeia para minha classe model? é isso?

Comment: isso.. a connection continua sendo ADO.NET

Comment: Beleza, vou dar uma olhada no Fonte que me mandou!

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de usar dapper junto ao EntityFramework?

Comment: sim, existe. veja: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/mt703432.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu discordo um pouco do que disseram aí. Ambos são micro ORMs.

O .NET trabalha com [*data providers*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Existe uma [API básica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) que toda aplicação .NET entenderá para acessar fontes de dados, especialmente banco de dados relacionais, já que o modelo foi pensado para este tipo e fonte. Qualquer banco de dados ou outra fonte pode criar um provedor de dados se sustentando nesta API e entregar os dados da melhor forma possível ao .NET. Em cima dessa API pode ser construído ORMs.

Um ORM é um mapeador objeto relacional, ou seja, ele cria um objeto baseado em campos do modelo relacional (isso foi relaxado e é possível usar outros modelos de acesso a dados) de um banco de dados, e o objeto pode ser transformado em campos que será atualizados no banco de dados. Um ORM é nada mais que isso. Se faz necessário não só pela forma como cada um é constituído, mas também porque a tipagem de cada um tende a ser diferente e pode ser necessário uma conversão ou adaptação.

Alguns ORMs são mais leves e fazem essencialmente isso, portanto são chamados de Micro ORMs, e os que possuem uma infraestrutura mais sofisticada dando outras funcionalidades, provavelmente implementando um mecanismo de repositório, são Full ORMs.

ADO.NET e Dapper são Micro ORMs. Entity Framework e nHibernate são *full*. Alguns dos *full* ORMs tendem a abstrair o banco de dados, ainda que isso pode não ser tão vantajoso quanto parece.

ADO.NET vem por padrão no .NET e possui uma infra mínima e até alguma pequena funcionalidade próxima ao de um repositório, mas de forma bastante limitada e um pouco problemática. Ele é sempre uma camada em cima do provedor de dados e por isso é mais lento. Se usar mal ele pode ser trágico. Mas o mesmo vale para um Full ORM. De uma certa forma, ele é até mais ORM que o Dapper por oferecer facilidades extras. Ele não cria um objeto POCO, mas cria um objeto que é acessado através de uma sintaxe de coleção de dados. É possível criar uma extensão que entregue um objeto POCO se for o que se deseja.

O Dapper, criado pela empresa proprietária deste site, também é uma camada em cima do provedor de dados e tem uma performance incrível, batendo o ADO.NET. Ele tem uma infra mais simples, e faz só o mapeamento básico e conversão sem nenhum mecanismo extra, até mesmo um CRUD precisa de um extra (disponível). É muito rápido, muito simples, e só supre uma deficiência do provedor de dados que não tem mesmo função de prover um modelo de dados. Ele cria um objeto normal.

Por incrível que pareça o Dapper tende a ser mais interessante por ser uma tecnologia criada com base em uso mais realista e ser algo mais moderno. Ainda que provisione menos funcionalidades, acaba funcionando melhor que o ADO.NET para a maioria dos casos. Em geral é possível criar aplicações muito simples e flexíveis com ele, além de muito performáticas.

Particularmente eu só usaria o ADO.NET se eu estiver acostumado com ele e não quiser mexer com outra coisa. Mesmo suas vantagens acabam sendo desvantagens em alguns pontos. Ou eu usaria o *data provider* direto, embora o ganho seja mínimo e a desvantagem acaba não compensando.

É possível usar ambos juntos, inclusive com o EF. Mas o ideal é não misturar tanto. Se o fizer precisa ter muita noção do que está fazendo para aproveitar o melhor de ambos e não criar novos problemas. De fato algumas pessoas usam o EF onde pode e quando fica muito complicado usá-lo vai mais na mão ou com as ferramentas próprias mais flexíveis do EF ou usando o Dapper ou ADO.NET.

Lembre-se que um Micro ORM sempre usará *queries* do banco de dados enquanto que um *full* ORM usará uma linguagem própria de consulta, no caso do EF o LINQ to Entities (até que não consiga o que quer e aí vai para o SQL também).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu comecei usar o dapper recentemente e estou maravilhado com ele, incrívelmente perfomático mesmo

Comment: Eu usei o Dapper numa aplicação desktop simples, ele é simples de instalar e de definir os objetos para ele. Eu gostei muito e vou usar em outros projetos futuramente. Tem o [Dapper Linq](https://github.com/ryanwatson/Dapper.Extensions.Linq) também :)

Answer (score 3):

## ADO.NET

Não é um ORM (Object-Relational Mapping ou Mapeamento objeto-relacional em português).

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/):

> O ADO.NET é um conjunto de classes que expõem serviços de acesso a dados para desenvolvedores do .NET Framework.
>
> O ADO.NET fornece um conjunto rico de componentes para criar aplicativos distribuídos e de compartilhamento de dados. Faz parte do .NET Framework, fornecendo acesso a dados de aplicativo relacionais e XML. O ADO.NET oferece suporte a uma variedade de necessidades de desenvolvimento, incluindo a criação de clientes front-end de banco de dados e objetos comerciais de camada intermediária usados por aplicativos, ferramentas, linguagens ou navegadores da Internet.

## Dapper

Também não é um Full ORM (ORM completo) propriamente dito. A própria [documentação](http://dapper-tutorial.net/) deixa isso claro:

> Is Dapper an ORM?
> Yes and no! People are still arguing about it. Dapper has earned the title of king of the C# Micro ORM but is considered by multiple people as a simple object mapper for .NET.

em tradução livre:

> Dapper é um ORM?
>
> Sim e não! As pessoas ainda estão discutindo sobre isso. Dapper ganhou o título de rei do C # Micro ORM, mas é considerado por muitas pessoas como um simples (*N.T.: simples no sentido "faz unicamente isso..."*) mapeador de objetos para o .NET.

## Micro ORM x Full ORM

ORM é Mapeador Objeto-Relacional e funciona como consultando e criando objetos, em tempo de execução, entre o código do cliente e o banco de dados relacional.
Os Full ORMs (ORM completos em tradução livre) fornecem vários recursos poderosos, como armazenamento em cache de objetos e consultas, controle de concorrência, linguagens de consulta orientada a objetos, etc..

O Micro ORM é basicamente um mapeador que cria objetos com base na consulta ao banco de dados. Eles abstraem boa parte dos recursos dos ORMs para ganhar em performance.

Limitações (vou usar o termos em inglês):

- Second Level caching;
- Lazy loading;
- Identity tracking;
- Change tracking;
- Modelo rico de mapeamento que suporta multiplas fontes de dados;
- unit-of-work API - essensialmente um método SubmitChanges() que
  aplica modificações em lote (batch)